# How to update custom joomla website without using joomla update package?

Tags: php, database, joomla, content-management-system, upgrade

My question is very simple to joomla experts that someone its not easy to do update a highly customized website that you don't want to loose. In that case which approach will be good. Please let me know.

I am thinking to update via FTP only required files to build...

Also When we update joomla website Is database also updated or only the files updated? Please tell.

Comment: The database is also usually updated when you update core joomla versions.

Comment: Did you change core files? Joomla is designed so that you can override all core files without modifying them in any way. What is it that you mean by highly customized?